# Xml Parsing jQuery <source> tag issue

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse my xml with jQuery and everyting is allright but `<source>` tag. Is `<source>` tag a reserved keyword or what? I've tried on both crome and firefox and it removes end tag of `<source>` node on the xml. Please have a look at the jsFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/H7S3r/

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery does indeed parse XML, it even has a special method that does it, and it's called $.parseXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That jQuery call you are making takes an html snippet, not xml.  `<source>` is an html tag that is not allowed to have an end tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source

So jQuery is trying to make the best of your invalid html by stripping out the illegal end tag.

As adeneo points out, if you want to use jQuery to parse XML, you should use `$.parseXML()`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/